# Настройка авторизации соединений сервера 1С Предприятие

Tags: сервер, авторизация, 1с

При программном подключении к серверу 1С:Предприятия сервер сначала принимает, а затем закрывает соединение: не пройдена авторизация. При этом для авторизации используется логин, который нигде у клиента не указан. Предполагаю, что он где-то в серверных настройках прописан. **Вопрос:** где он прописан и как его поменять?
Логи сервера (технологический журнал):

```
> 03:15.484001-0,CONN,0,process=ragent,ClientID=4427,Protected=1,Txt='Accepted,
> client=(2)192.168.166.181:50920, server=(2)192.168.3.30:1740'
> 03:15.562002-0,CONN,2,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,Txt=Srvr:
> SrcUserName1: nsk5025nk$@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
> 03:15.562003-0,CONN,2,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,Txt=Srvr:
> DstUserName1: 1c-subs@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL(MYDOMAIN.LOCAL\1c-subs)
> 03:15.562004-3,CALL,1,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,Interface=7f58f27d-5ad8-43a1-aa1e-c982f41bed5c,IName=IRemoteCreatorService,Method=0,CallID=-396525813,MName=createRemoteInstance,Memory=17930,MemoryPeak=18416,InBytes=0,OutBytes=0
> 03:15.578001-0,CONN,2,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,Txt=Srvr:
> DstUserName2: MYDOMAIN\1c-subs(MYDOMAIN\1c-subs)
> 03:15.578003-0,SCOM,3,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,Func='setSrcProcessName(##AdminProcess##,##AdminProcess##)'
> 03:15.578004-4,CALL,1,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,Interface=7f58f27d-5ad8-43a1-aa1e-c982f41bed5c,IName=IRemoteCreatorService,Method=0,CallID=-396525744,MName=createRemoteInstance,Memory=845229,MemoryPeak=846384,InBytes=408,OutBytes=0
> 03:15.594001-1,CALL,2,process=ragent,p:processName=##AdminProcess##,t:clientID=4427,t:applicationName=COMConsole,t:computerName=1c-subs,Method=methodsCount,CallID=-396525739
> 03:15.594005-1,SCALL,3,process=ragent,p:processName=##AdminProcess##,t:clientID=4427,t:applicationName=COMConsole,t:computerName=1c-subs,ClientID=4415,Interface=0459eaa0-589f-4a6d-9eed-c1a7461c8e3f,IName=IClusterRegistry,Method=0,CallID=81613048,MName=getRegistryParams
> 03:15.594006-3,CALL,2,process=ragent,p:processName=##AdminProcess##,t:clientID=4427,t:applicationName=COMConsole,t:computerName=1c-subs,Interface=73cdaa77-2afc-436c-b738-58c772e3a0bf,IName=IServerClusterAdmin,Method=0,CallID=-396525738,MName=ibRegistries,Memory=13943,MemoryPeak=17823,InBytes=0,OutBytes=0
> 03:15.594010-1,SCALL,3,process=ragent,p:processName=##AdminProcess##,t:clientID=4427,t:applicationName=COMConsole,t:computerName=1c-subs,ClientID=4415,Interface=0459eaa0-589f-4a6d-9eed-c1a7461c8e3f,IName=IClusterRegistry,Method=14,CallID=81613049,MName=ibrAuthenticate
> 03:15.594011-3,CALL,2,process=ragent,p:processName=##AdminProcess##,t:clientID=4427,t:applicationName=COMConsole,t:computerName=1c-subs,Interface=73cdaa77-2afc-436c-b738-58c772e3a0bf,IName=IServerClusterAdmin,Method=10,CallID=-396525737,MName=regAuthenticate,RetExcp='Ошибка
> операции администрирования Администратор кластера не
> аутентифицирован',Memory=-120,MemoryPeak=3936,InBytes=0,OutBytes=0
> 03:15.594014-1,CALL,2,process=ragent,p:processName=##AdminProcess##,t:clientID=4427,t:applicationName=COMConsole,t:computerName=1c-subs,Method=Release,CallID=-396525735
> 03:15.594016-0,EXCP,1,process=ragent,ClientID=4427,Exception=NetDataExchangeException,Descr='server_addr=(2)192.168.166.181:50920
> descr=recv returns zero, disconnected line=2355
> file=src\DataExchangeServerImpl.cpp'
> 03:15.594017-0,EXCPCNTX,0,ClientComputerName=,ServerComputerName=,UserName=,ConnectString=
> 03:15.594018-3,EXCPCNTX,0,SrcName=MEM,OSThread=8804,process=ragent
> 03:15.594019-0,CONN,1,process=ragent,ClientID=4427,Txt=Incomming
> connection closed: client disconnected
> 03:15.594020-32020,CONN,0,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,t:clientID=4427,t:computerName=1c-subs,t:applicationName=COMConsole,t:connectID=0,Calls=6
> 03:15.594021-16019,SCOM,2,process=ragent,t:clientID=4427,ProcessName=##AdminProcess##,SrcProcessName=##AdminProcess##
```

Удалось понять, что `SrcUserName1: nsk5025nk$@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL` - это имя пользователя, под которым запущена служба Агента 1С Предприятия. А вот откуда берутся имена `DstUserName1: 1c-subs@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL(MYDOMAIN.LOCAL\1c-subs)` и `DstUserName2: MYDOMAIN\1c-subs(MYDOMAIN\1c-subs)`, мне непонятно. Прошу подсказать, где эти настройки.
P.S. `MYDOMAIN` я подставил сюда вместо реального имени домена.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

> 'Ошибка операции администрирования Администратор кластера не
>   аутентифицирован'

Необходимо запустить консоль управления(MMC) "Администрирование серверов 1С:Предприятия" и там добавить пользователя или изменить пароль.
http://v8.1c.ru/overview/Term_000000595.htm

Comment: Пользователь добавлен. Администратор кластера добавлен. Проблема остается.

Comment: 1. Какая версия 1С сервера? (в 8.3 добавили профили безопасности)
2. Какой код используете для подключения к серверу?

Comment: Платформа 1с - 8.3.6.2100 
Сервер БД - MS SQL 2012 
ОС Windows 8.1 в домене.
К серверу подключаюсь через 1C-java-api с сайта ИТС (java-библиотеки, написанные фирмой 1С в 2014 году), использую их демо-пример.

Comment: Посмотри документацию по "Сервер администрирования кластера серверов" http://its.1c.ru/db/v837doc#bookmark:cs:TI000000189 там описан "ras" сервер и клиент "rac"(они идут в поставке платформы 1С), если настроишь сервер(и подключишься rac-клиентом) то сможешь подключиться с Java client-ом.